# Errors with PHPMyAdmin on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, phpmyadmin

**UPDATED:** Now the page shows but it can't connect and I get the following PHP error when logging is turned on for phpmyadmin:

> mysqli_real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: gethostbyname failed.
>   errno=0

config.inc.php looks like this:

```
* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = ':/cloudsql/app-engine-name:sql-instance-name';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'socket';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot'] = true;

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

$cfg['McryptDisableWarning'] = true;
$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] = true;
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 60;
$cfg['CheckConfigurationPermissions'] = false;

$cfg['DBG']['sql'] = true;
$cfg['Error_Handler']['display'] = true;

//tried this too: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
```

However, once I login with the database credentials (root and the pw I set in the console), <s>the page is just blank. Nothing, no error- nothing when inspecting the source.</s> (now it works, blank page had to do with faulty redirect)

Help? :)

This is using latest phpmyadmin- 4.2.5

Comment: What does it say in the App Engine log console?

Comment: Where do I find that? At console.developers.google.com I hit the app and then COMPUTE -> APP ENGINE -> LOGS, but it only gives me basic access logs, don't see any errors...

Comment: What was your fix for the faulty redirect?

Comment: dunno man, it was 5 years ago :)

Answer (score 0):

You've set the `connect_type` directive to socket, but then put something in the 'host' fiend, which is used for `connect_type` tcp. This is what's confusing PHP and giving you the error message; that's not a valid hostname/IP address and that's what the error message is (somewhat cryptically) reporting. It appears as if you're trying to put your socket path there, but haven't quite got the format right.

Start by removing the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']` line entirely and give it a shot. If your PHP installation is configured with the proper socket, it will work based on that default value. If that doesn't work, it's easy enough to instruct phpMyAdmin to use the proper socket using the directive [$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_socket).

You should also double-check that you have the proper socket path, because I'm not familiar with a file path that would start with a colon. A quick Google search [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20164797/2385479) an appropriate socket with GAE would be something like `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/cloudsql/APPENGINE-ID:DATABASE-INSTANCE-ID';` but you should refer to your documentation or support contacts for help with your specific configuration.