# Codeigniter with GAE cloud sql

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine, mysqli

I'm creating a rest API with Codeigniter framework which will be hosted in the GAE and it communicate with a cloud SQL database.

I already changed and configured my Codeigniter framework according to the steps described here. [How do I connect to a Google Cloud SQL database using CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032393/how-do-i-connect-to-a-google-cloud-sql-database-using-codeigniter)

But when I call         `$this->load->database();`
in my controller it result in the following error.

```
Severity: Warning

Message: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 120
```

Please help me to figure out this problem as I have already wasted so many time on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which version of Codeigniter you use, however, since version 3.0 this is the default code of the db_connect function in the framework

```
public function db_connect($persistent = FALSE)
{
    // Do we have a socket path?
    if ($this->hostname[0] === '/')
    {
        $hostname = NULL;
        $port = NULL;
        $socket = $this->hostname;
    }
    else
    {
        // Persistent connection support was added in PHP 5.3.0
        $hostname = ($persistent === TRUE && is_php('5.3'))
            ? 'p:'.$this->hostname : $this->hostname;
        $port = empty($this->port) ? NULL : $this->port;
        $socket = NULL;
    }

    $client_flags = ($this->compress === TRUE) ? MYSQLI_CLIENT_COMPRESS : 0;
    $this->_mysqli = mysqli_init();

    $this->_mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    if (isset($this->stricton))
    {
        if ($this->stricton)
        {
            $this->_mysqli->options(MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ",", "STRICT_ALL_TABLES")');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_mysqli->options(MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND,
                'SET SESSION sql_mode =
                REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                @@sql_mode,
                "STRICT_ALL_TABLES,", ""),
                ",STRICT_ALL_TABLES", ""),
                "STRICT_ALL_TABLES", ""),
                "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,", ""),
                ",STRICT_TRANS_TABLES", ""),
                "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES", "")'
            );
        }
    }

    if (is_array($this->encrypt))
    {
        $ssl = array();
        empty($this->encrypt['ssl_key'])    OR $ssl['key']    = $this->encrypt['ssl_key'];
        empty($this->encrypt['ssl_cert'])   OR $ssl['cert']   = $this->encrypt['ssl_cert'];
        empty($this->encrypt['ssl_ca'])     OR $ssl['ca']     = $this->encrypt['ssl_ca'];
        empty($this->encrypt['ssl_capath']) OR $ssl['capath'] = $this->encrypt['ssl_capath'];
        empty($this->encrypt['ssl_cipher']) OR $ssl['cipher'] = $this->encrypt['ssl_cipher'];

        if ( ! empty($ssl))
        {
            if (isset($this->encrypt['ssl_verify']))
            {
                if ($this->encrypt['ssl_verify'])
                {
                    defined('MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT') && $this->_mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, TRUE);
                }
                // Apparently (when it exists), setting MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT
                // to FALSE didn't do anything, so PHP 5.6.16 introduced yet another
                // constant ...
                //
                // https://secure.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.6.16
                // https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68344
                elseif (defined('MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL_DONT_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT'))
                {
                    $this->_mysqli->options(MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL_DONT_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, TRUE);
                }
            }

            $client_flags |= MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL;
            $this->_mysqli->ssl_set(
                isset($ssl['key'])    ? $ssl['key']    : NULL,
                isset($ssl['cert'])   ? $ssl['cert']   : NULL,
                isset($ssl['ca'])     ? $ssl['ca']     : NULL,
                isset($ssl['capath']) ? $ssl['capath'] : NULL,
                isset($ssl['cipher']) ? $ssl['cipher'] : NULL
            );
        }
    }

    if ($this->_mysqli->real_connect($hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database, $port, $socket, $client_flags))
    {
        // Prior to version 5.7.3, MySQL silently downgrades to an unencrypted connection if SSL setup fails
        if (
            ($client_flags & MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL)
            && version_compare($this->_mysqli->client_info, '5.7.3', '<=')
            && empty($this->_mysqli->query("SHOW STATUS LIKE 'ssl_cipher'")->fetch_object()->Value)
        )
        {
            $this->_mysqli->close();
            $message = 'MySQLi was configured for an SSL connection, but got an unencrypted connection instead!';
            log_message('error', $message);
            return ($this->db->db_debug) ? $this->db->display_error($message, '', TRUE) : FALSE;
        }

        return $this->_mysqli;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

From this code, what I could  figure out is you can directly pass the socket as an array parameter in your database.php file. Did you ever try that?

Also it's not recommended to modify framework's core files. It might lead to other issues.

**Edit**:
Else you could create a custom library function to connect to the database manually using the default parameters